# typoscript lib set variable for controller

Tags: typo3, typoscript

to modify my breadcrumbs on certain pages, I added a plugin which is supposed to add something to my breadcrumb values. But I need a certain get variable value and it just doesn't work:

```
lib.tippBreadcrumbs = USER_INT
lib.tippBreadcrumbs{
    vendorName = Package
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
    extensionName = SomethingArticles
    pluginName = ArticleBreadcrumbs
    controller = Article
    action = articleBreadcrumbs
    settings.articleCategory = TEXT
    settings.articleCategory.data = gp:tx_somethingarticles_categorydetail|articleCategory
}
```

In my Article controller in my articleBreadcrumbs action, my settings array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [articleCategory] => Array
        (
            [data] => 
            [_typoScriptNodeValue] => gp:tx_somethingarticles_categorydetail|articleCategory
        )
)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not know the answer, but another smart person did:
http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-typo3v4mvc/2011-October/010591.html

learned something myself